# device tree overlay for heartbeat not working

Tags: overlay, beagleboneblack

First of all, hello!

I wrote a device tree overlay for heartbeat function on a gpio (you can see the dts file below).

It is loadad successfully, and I could see the trigger file in userspace:

```
root@beaglebone:~# cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots 
0: PF----  -1 
1: PF----  -1 
2: PF----  -1 
3: PF----  -1 
4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-univ-emmc
6: P-O-L-   1 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,issd-heartbeat

root@beaglebone:~# cat /sys/class/leds/beaglebone\:yellow\:usr0/trigger 
none nand-disk usb-gadget usb-host mmc0 mmc1 timer oneshot [heartbeat] backlight gpio default-on
```

Everything looks ok but I cannot see heartbeat on the pin.

I verified the led is working, I can pull it low and high with no problem when it's configured as output gpio.

I don't know where to look now, so if anyone can direct me, it's enough. Thanks.

DTS file:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    /* identification */
    part-number = "issd-heartbeat";
    version = "00A0";

    /* state the resources this cape uses */
    exclusive-use =
        /* the pin header uses */
        "P8.8", /* heart beat LED*/


        /* the hardware ip uses */
        "gpio2_3";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            indicator_pins: indicator_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    0x094 0x07
                >;
            };
        };
    };


    fragment@14 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            indicator_pins {
                compatible = "gpio-leds";
                status = "okay";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&indicator_pins>;

                led0 {
                    label = "beaglebone:yellow:usr0";
                    gpios = <&gpio3 3 0x00>;         /* gpio3 is gpio2*/
                    linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
                    default-state = "off";
                };
            };
        };
    };

};
```

Comment: I noticed that wrong pin being initialized! The offset value is correct according to documentations. Instead of pin 37, pin 47 is initialized. I still could not find why.

Comment: I tried the same overlay with debian 7 with kernel 3.8 and it worked fine.